# Is inconsistent when a liquid evaporates, its volume changes, and pressure and temperature are constant?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, water, phase-transition

> We know that ordinarily, pressure, volume, and temperature cannot change individually without one affecting the other. Yet when a liquid evaporates, its volume changes, even though its pressure and temperature are constant. Is this inconsistent?

(From *University Physics with Modern Physics* 13th Edition)

I think it is inconsistent because when, for example, water evaporates two things occur:

1. The temperature remains constant. In phase transition, the water temperature remains unchanged.
2. The pressure CHANGES because there is less volume.

I am not very confident with the second part (2).

What do you think?

Comment: InfZero, you need to be more specific.  If water evaporates in an open container, its pressure is equal to the ambient pressure.  "Less volume" probably doesn't apply in this case.  If water evaporates in a closed container, this will cause the pressure to increase.  And note, at constant temperature, there is an equal amount of water evaporating and condensing in a closed container, so the pressure stays constant.

Comment: Consider the conditions under which *"We know that ordinarily, pressure, volume, and temperature cannot change individually without one affecting the other. "* has actually been examined up to this point in your education. Are they consistent with the process that you are considering now?

Answer (score 1):

The apparent inconsistency stems from the fact you are not considering the quantity of matter in each phase changes.
If you look at the Perfect Gas state equation,

$$PV = nRT,$$

there is a term $n$ which counts how many molecules of gas are there. So when water is evaporating/condensing, pressure and temperature can stay the same while the volume occupied by water vapour changes because the number of molecules in that state changes. Likewise, the number of molecules in liquid state changes and an analogous argument is made for the liquid phase.

Answer (score 0):

You are right to be unsure about part (2) because it is not true:

> When (pure) water evaporates under constant temperature, pressure **must** stay constant.